# Dijkstra's Challenge

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, matrix

### Presented in honor of [APL as an interactive tool turning 50 this year](http://www.dyalog.com/50-years-of-apl.htm)

#### [Background](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APLQA.htm)

> [Ken [Iverson]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_E._Iverson) presented his paper *[Formalism in Programming Languages](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/FPL.htm)* in August 1963 at a Working Conference on Mechanical Language Structures, Princeton, N.J. The list of conferees is full of famous and soon-to-be famous names, and a few future Turing Award winners (Backus, Curry, Dijkstra, Floyd, Iverson, Newell, Perlis, Wilkes). The paper also records the discussion that occurred after the presentation, ending with an exchange between Ken and [[Edsger] Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra), in which Ken’s reply to Dijkstra’s question was a one-liner.

#### [Challenge](http://keiapl.org/anec/#Dijkstra)

> How would you represent a more complex operation, for example, the sum of all elements of a matrix ***M*** which are equal to the sum of the corresponding row and column indices?

Write a snippet or expression (no need for a full program or function) to calculate the sum of each element in a given integer matrix which is equal to the sum of its indices. Or, as FryAmTheEggman puts it: given a matrix ***M*** with elements ***a***<sub>ij</sub> return the sum of each ***a***<sub>ij</sub> where ***a***<sub>ij</sub> = i + j.

You may assume the matrix already being in a variable or memory location, or you may take it as an argument or input. You may use either 0 or 1 based indices.

#### Test cases

`0` for empty matrix

```
2
```

`0` for 0 based indices or `2` for 1-based

```
1 5 2
9 4 2
5 9 6
```

`2` for 0 based or `10` for 1 based

```
 0 3  0  4
 0 4  1  4
 4 3  1  2
-2 4 -2 -1
```

`11`

```
3 -1 3 3
3 -1 3 1
```

`6` for 0 based or `3` for 1 based

#### Anecdote

Iverson's answer was ++/(***M*** = ***⍳***¹ ⨢ ***⍳***¹)//***M***, which is neither valid in the *Iverson Notation* as defined in *A Programming Language*, nor in what eventually became APL. In Iverson notation, it would have been +/(***M*** = ***⍳***¹(*μ*(***M***)) ⨢ ***⍳***¹(*ν*(***M***)))/***M***. In the very first versions of APL it was `+/(,M=(⍳1↑⍴M)∘.+⍳1↓⍴M)/,M`.

Comment: _in which Ken’s reply to Dijkstra’s question was a one-liner._ But then that one-liner was wrong?

Comment: Do I need to output it or print it out, or can I just write down the expression as a snippet?

Comment: @LuisMendo No, Iverson was actively designing the language, and at that iteration, his one-liner was correct. "APL" became famous with the publishing of the book ***A** **P**rogramming **L**anguage*, but at the time of publishing, the second expression was needed. Neither of these notations were ever implemented to be machine-executable.

Comment: @LeakyNun *Write a snippet or expression **to calculate***

Comment: @Adám Thanks. It makes more sense now

Comment: Can I store the output in a variable?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes you can.

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 10 bytes

```
3#fbb+y=*s
```

The input has rows separated by `;`. For example: `[1 5 2; 9 4 2; 5 9 6]`. 1-based indexing is used.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MyNmYmIreT0qcw&input=WzMgLTEgMyAzOyAzIC0xIDMgMV0K) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YAozI2ZiYit5PSpzCkRU&input=W10KWzJdClsxIDUgMjsgOSA0IDI7IDUgOSA2XQpbMCAzIDAgNDsgMCA0IDEgNDsgNCAzIDEgMjsgLTIgNCAtMiAtMV0KWzMgLTEgMyAzOyAzIC0xIDMgMV0).

#### Explanation

I'll use the example with input `[3 -1 3 3; 3 -1 3 1]` in the explanation.

```
3#f    % Three-output find: for all nonzero values of implicit input matrix, pushes
       % three column vectors with row indices, column indices, and values
       %   Stack contains: [1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2], [1;1;2;2;3;3;4;4], [3;3;-1;-1;3;3;3;1]
bb     % Bubble up twice: move vectors of row and column indices to top
       %   Stack contains: [3;3;-1;-1;3;3;3;1], [1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2], [1;1;2;2;3;3;4;4]
+      % Element-wise sum of top two arrays
       %   Stack contains: [3;3;-1;-1;3;3;3;1], [2;3;3;4;4;5;5;6]
y      % Duplicate the vector of nonzero values onto the top of the stack
       %   Stack contains: [3;3;-1;-1;3;3;3;1], [2;3;3;4;4;5;5;6], [3;3;-1;-1;3;3;3;1] 
=      % Element-wise equality test of top two arrays
       %   Stack contains: [3;3;-1;-1;3;3;3;1], [0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0]
*      % Element-wise multiply of top two arrays
       %   Stack contains: [0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0]
s      % Sum of array
       %   Stack contains: 3
```

Answer (score 9):

## APL, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

**1 byte thanks to @jimmy23013.**

1-indexed.

The array is stored in the variable `m`.

```
+/,m×m=+/¨⍳⍴m
+/∊m∩¨+/¨⍳⍴m
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=+/%u220Am%u2229%A8+/%A8%u2373%u2374m%20%u2190%202%204%20%u2374%203%20%AF1%203%203%203%20%AF1%203%201&run)

Based on [the answer in J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85793/48934), which is a language based on APL.

In TryAPL, to key in: `` +/m`em`c`1+/`1`i`rm ``

With the array: `` +/m`em`c`1+/`1`i`rm `[ 2 4 `r 3 `21 3 3 3 `21 3 1 ``

#### Explanation

```
+/∊m∩¨+/¨⍳⍴m
           m    temp ← variable
          ⍴     temp ← shape of temp
         ⍳      temp ← a 2D array where each element is
                       the corresponding index. for the
                       example, this gives:
                       ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
                       │1 1│1 2│1 3│1 4│
                       ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
                       │2 1│2 2│2 3│2 4│
                       └───┴───┴───┴───┘
      +/¨       each element in temp ← its sum
   m∩¨          temp ← intersect each element in temp with the variable
+/              temp ← sum of temp
```

Comment: Finally, I was waiting for this one.

Comment: I'm not sure the "To key in:" is a good idea. It only applies to TryAPL and RIDE, but not to the main product. At least you can explain that `\`` means "APL key".

Comment: `+/∊m∩¨+/¨⍳⍴m`.

Comment: @jimmy23013 That's really good!

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript, <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```
a.map((b,i)=>b.map((c,j)=>r+=c==i+j&&c),r=0)|r
```

Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder pointing out that snippets are allowed.

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 46 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
\d+
$*
M!`(?<=(\S* |.*¶)*)(?<-1>1)+\b(?(1)1)
1
```

Input uses space and linefeed separators to represent the matrix. Indices are 0-based.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqCk0hYCg_PD0oXFMqIHwuKsK2KSopKD88LTE-MSkrXGIoPygxKTEpCjE&input=MCAzIDAgNAowIDQgMSA0CjQgMyAxIDIKLTIgNCAtMiAtMQ)

#### Explanation

Not quite the kind of challenge Retina was made for, but it's doing surprisingly well... :)

**Stage 1: Substitution**

```
\d+
$*
```

This simply expands all the integers in the string as unary numbers using `1` as the unary digit. Negative numbers like `-3` will simply become things like `-111`.

**Stage 2: Match**

```
M!`(?<=(\S* |.*¶)*)(?<-1>1)+\b(?(1)1)
```

Due to the `!` option, this prints all the matches of the given regex. Said regex uses [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/1633117) to check whether the current number is the same as the sum of its indices.

To do that, we first determine the sum of indices with the lookbehind `(?<=(\S* |.*¶)*)`. This adds one capture for each number in front of the current one on the same line (via `\S*` ) as well as one capture for each line in front of the current one (via `.*¶`) to group `1`. Hence, we get the zero-based sum of indices as a result.

Then we try to match the entire next number while removing captures from this stack with `(?<-1>1)+\b`. And then we make the match fail if any captures are left on group `1` with `(?(1)1)` to ensure equality.

Note that negative numbers are never matched, because the lookbehind cannot get past the `-` in front of list of `1`s and the `(?<-1>1)+` can't match it either.

This gives us a list of all the unary numbers which equal the sum of their indices.

**Stage 3: Match**

```
1
```

We end with another match stage, but without the `!` option, this just counts the number of matches, which both sums all the unary numbers from the previous result and also converts that sum back to decimal.

Comment: Can you use unary as input?

Comment: @LeakyNun Don't know, I've kinda been trying to avoid it. It just seems too hacky, especially since Retina has no trouble with the conversion any more.

Answer (score 4):

## J, 15 bytes

```
+/,M*M=+/&i./$M
```

Uses zero-based indexing and assumes the matrix is already stored in variable *M*.

### Explanation

```
+/,M*M=+/&i./$M
             $a  Get the shape of M
            /    Insert between the shape
         &i.     Create a range from 0 to each end exclusive
       +/        Forms a table which is the sum of each row and column index
     M=          1 if the element is equal to its index sum else 0
   M*            Multiply by their values
  ,              Flatten
+/               Reduce using addition to get the sum
```

Comment: Not only shortest until now; +1 for doing it in an Iverson language.

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 10 bytes

**4 bytes thanks to Adnan.**

1-indexed.

```
L€R€+"LR$=³×³FS
L€R€+"LR$=×³FS
J€+"J=×⁸FS
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=SuKCrCsiSj3Dl8KzRlM&input=&args=W1szLC0xLDMsM10sWzMsLTEsMywxXV0)

[Verify all testcases at once.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=SuKCrCsiSj3Dl-KBuEZTCsOH4oKs&input=&args=W10sW1syXV0sW1sxLDUsMl0sWzksNCwyXSxbNSw5LDZdXSxbWzAsMywwLDRdLFswLDQsMSw0XSxbNCwzLDEsMl0sWy0yLDQsLTIsLTFdXSxbWzMsLTEsMywzXSxbMywtMSwzLDFdXQ)
(Slightly modified.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but can you do `J€` instead of `L€R€`?

Comment: Oh my God, you're a genius.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 24 bytes

```
sum(M[M==row(M)+col(M)])
```

1-based.
Test cases:

```
> M<-matrix(nrow=0,ncol=0)
> M
<0 x 0 matrix>
> sum(M[M==row(M)+col(M)])
[1] 0
> M<-matrix(2,nrow=1,ncol=1)
> M
     [,1]
[1,]    2
> sum(M[M==row(M)+col(M)])
[1] 2
> M<-matrix(c(1,9,5,5,4,9,2,2,6),nrow=3)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    2
[2,]    9    4    2
[3,]    5    9    6
> sum(M[M==row(M)+col(M)])
[1] 10
> M<-matrix(c(0,0,4,-2,3,4,3,4,0,1,1,-2,4,4,2,-1),nrow=4)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    3    0    4
[2,]    0    4    1    4
[3,]    4    3    1    2
[4,]   -2    4   -2   -1
> sum(M[M==row(M)+col(M)])
[1] 11
> M<-matrix(c(3,3,-1,-1,3,3,3,1),nrow=2)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3   -1    3    3
[2,]    3   -1    3    1
> sum(M[M==row(M)+col(M)])
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, <s>23</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

*Thanks to Peter Taylor for saving 3 bytes.*

```
ee{~_@f-_,,.=.*~}%1b
```

Expects the matrix to be on the stack and leaves the sum instead. Indices are zero-based in either case.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B%5B%200%203%20%200%20%204%5D%0A%20%5B%200%204%20%201%20%204%5D%0A%20%5B%204%203%20%201%20%202%5D%0A%20%5B-2%204%20-2%20-1%5D%5D%0A%0Aee%7B~_%40f-_%2C%2C.%3D.*~%7D%251b)

Comment: You can save a couple with `_,,` instead of the inner `ee` and `.` for the inner loop: `ee{~_,,@f+1$.=.*~}%1b`

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah neat, thank you. :)

Comment: In fact, there's one more, by doing a kind of meet-in-the-middle: `ee{~_@f-_,,.=.*~}%1b`

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 - <del>60</del> 57 bytes

It's a code snippet, so it would be a few more bytes if I actually returned the value, I guess.
`e=enumerate;sum(i*(x+y==i)for x,r in e(a)for y,i in e(r))`

Thanks for the help Leaky Num :-)

Quick explanation. `a` is an array holding numbers. Simply iterate through indexes and sum up all values where the value equals the sum of the index.

Comment: [`e=enumerate;sum(i*(x+y==i)for x,r in e(a)for y,i in e(r))`](http://ideone.com/MHo5jx)

Comment: oh it didn't work. so its 57 bytes now : ( I added a quick explanation

Comment: You might want to include the link I just gave you.

Answer (score 3):

## k4, 24 bytes

Assumes the matrix is stored in `m`.

```
+//7h$m*m=(!#m)+/:\:!#*m
```

This is one of those puzzles where the simplifications involved in designing k from APL (and J) really hurt—k’s `!` is the equivalent of APL’s `⍳` but only works on vectors, so I have to assemble the matrix of indices myself; inner product is one character in APL but five in k; and I lose three characters to handling the empty matrix properly because k doesn’t have strongly-typed matrices.

Comment: On the other hand, you have a powerful language which is much more consistent, and with much fewer primitives to learn.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

0-indexed.

```
ss.e.e*ZqZ+kYb
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ss.e.e%2aZqZ%2BkYb&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5D%0A%5B%5B2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C5%2C2%5D%2C%5B9%2C4%2C2%5D%2C%5B5%2C9%2C6%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C3%2C0%2C4%5D%2C%5B0%2C4%2C1%2C4%5D%2C%5B4%2C3%2C1%2C2%5D%2C%5B-2%2C4%2C-2%2C-1%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B3%2C-1%2C3%2C3%5D%2C%5B3%2C-1%2C3%2C1%5D%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 43 bytes

```
%{$j=0;$_|%{$o+=$_*($_-eq$i+$j++)};$i++};$o
```

As a snippet. Usage is to explicitly pipe the matrix to this (see examples below). Assumes that `$i`, and `$o` are either null or zero at the start (I've explicitly set them as such in the examples below), and utilizes 0-index.

Does a foreach loop on each row of the matrix. We set `$j` to `0`, and then go through each element of the row in another loop `$_|%{...}`. Each inner loop, we increment `$o` by the current element multiplied by a Boolean `($_-eq$i+$j++)`, meaning if that Boolean is `$TRUE`, it'll be `1`, otherwise `0`. Then we exit the inner loop, increment `$i`, and start the next row. Finally, we leave `$o` on the pipeline at the end.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> $o=0;$i=0;$j=0;@(@(3,-1,3,3),@(3,-1,3,1))|%{$j=0;$_|%{$o+=$_*($_-eq$i+$j++)};$i++};$o
6

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> $o=0;$i=0;$j=0;@(@(0,3,0,4),@(0,4,1,4),@(4,3,1,2),@(-2,4,-2,-1))|%{$j=0;$_|%{$o+=$_*($_-eq$i+$j++)};$i++};$o
11
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 63 bytes

With z as a two-dimensional array of numbers:

```
s=0;z.each_index{|i|z[i].each_index{|j|s+=i+j if z[i][j]==i+j}}
```

Not terribly exciting at all.

If z is a flattened array with x and y having the sizes of the arrays, such as:

```
x=z.size
y=z[0].size
z=z.flatten
```

Then we have this monstrousity - perhaps more ruby-ish with it's fancy products and zips, but actually larger:

```
(1..x).to_a.product((1..y).to_a).zip(z).inject(0){|s,n|s+(n[0][0]+n[0][1]==n[1]+2?n[1]:0)}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a fancier array or enumerator method that would shorten it, I haven't found it yet, but I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

### Actually, 21 bytes

```
ñ`i╗ñ"i╜+@;(=*"£Mi`MΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=w7FgaeKVl8OxImnilZwrQDsoPSoiwqNNaWBNzqM&input=W1swLDMsMCw0XSxbMCw0LDEsNF0sWzQsMywxLDJdLFstMiw0LC0yLC0xXV0)

Thanks to Leaky Nun for making me stop being lazy and finally write this.

This uses 0-indexed matrices, and takes input as a nested list.

Explanation:

```
ñ`i╗ñ"i╜+@;(=*"£Mi`MΣ
ñ                      enumerate input
 `i╗ñ"i╜+@;(=*"£Mi`M   for each (i, row) pair:
  i╗                     flatten, store i in register 0
    ñ                    enumerate the row
     "i╜+@;(=*"£M        for each (j, val) pair:
      i╜+                  flatten, add i to j
         @;(               make an extra copy of val, bring i+j back to top
            =              compare equality of i+j and val
             *             multiply (0 if not equal, val if they are)
                 i       flatten the resulting list
                    Σ  sum the values
```

Comment: [same byte-count, without function delimiters or registers](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OztsckBGbHLiiJnimYLOo0DimYJpO2HimYA94pmAKs6j&input=W1swLDMsMCw0XSxbMCw0LDEsNF0sWzQsMywxLDJdLFstMiw0LC0yLC0xXV0)

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab/Octave, 48 bytes

1-indexed.

Will not handle the first test case because `[1:0]` has size 1x0 for some reason

```
sum(sum(M.*(M-[1:size(M,1)]'-[1:size(M,2)]==0)))
```

Tested in Octave 3.

Full program:

```
M = [2]
sum(sum(M.*(M-[1:size(M,1)]'-[1:size(M,2)]==0)))
M = [1 5 2; 9 4 2; 5 9 6]
sum(sum(M.*(M-[1:size(M,1)]'-[1:size(M,2)]==0)))
M = [ 0 3  0  4; 0 4  1  4; 4 3  1  2;-2 4 -2 -1]
sum(sum(M.*(M-[1:size(M,1)]'-[1:size(M,2)]==0)))
M = [ 3 -1 3 3; 3 -1 3 1]
sum(sum(M.*(M-[1:size(M,1)]'-[1:size(M,2)]==0)))
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! In Octave you can do `sum((M.*(M-[1:size(M,1)]'-[1:size(M,2)]==0))(:))`. Also, I think you can change `==0` by and initial `~` to further reduce byte count. Finally, note that you need to handle all test cases or else the question should be [deleted](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7990/36398)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 70 bytes

1-indexed.

```lua
s=0 for i=1,#a do for j=1,#a[i]do s=i+j==a[i][j]and s+i+j or s end end
```

Bonus: it works for ragged arrays!

Input stored in `a`, output stored in `s`.

## Full program:

```lua
function Dijkstras_Challenge(a)
    s=0 for i=1,#a do for j=1,#a[i]do s=i+j==a[i][j]and s+i+j or s end end
    print(s)
end

Dijkstras_Challenge({})
Dijkstras_Challenge({{2}})
Dijkstras_Challenge({{1,5,2},{9,4,2},{5,9,6}})
Dijkstras_Challenge({{0,3,0,4},{0,4,1,4},{4,3,1,2},{-2,4,-2,-1}})
Dijkstras_Challenge({{3,-1,3,3},{3,-1,3,1}})
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 59 bytes

```
foreach($a as$y=>$r)foreach($r as$x=>$v)$s+=($v==$x+$y)*$v;
```

expects array $a defined; must be empty or 2-dimensional, 0-indexed.
calculates sum to $s (previously 0 or undefined - 0 equals NULL)
insert `+2` before final `)` for 1-indexed behaviour

Happy Birthday APL!

**functions and test suite**

```
function f0($a) { foreach($a as$y=>$r)foreach($r as$x=>$v)$s+=($v==$x+$y)*$v;return $s|0; }
function f1($a) { foreach($a as$y=>$r)foreach($r as$x=>$v)$s+=($v==$x+$y+2)*$v;return $s|0;}
$samples = [
    [], 0, 0,
    [[2]], 0, 2,
    [[1,5,2],[9,4,2],[5,9,6]], 2, 10,
    [[0,3,0,4],[0,4,1,4],[4,3,1,2],[-2,4,-2,-1]],11,11,
    [[3,-1,3,3],[3,-1,3,1]],6,3
];
function test($x,$e,$y){static $h='<table border=1><tr><th>input</th><th>output</th><th>expected</th><th>ok?</th></tr>';echo"$h<tr><td>",out($x),'</td><td>',out($y),'</td><td>',out($e),'</td><td>',cmp($e,$y)?'N':'Y',"</td></tr>";$h='';}
while($samples)
{
    $a=array_shift($samples);
    test($a,'B0:'.array_shift($samples),'B0:'.f0($a));
    test($a,'B1:'.array_shift($samples),'B1:'.f1($a));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
{iiʰI-ʰ=∧Ihh}ᶠ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wvzoz89QGT91TG2wfdSz3zMiofbhtgfb//9EK0bE60dFGsSDSUMdUxwjIsNQxAdOmOpY6ZmAZAx1jHQMdEyATSOoYglkmQDFDsLp4I6AgkIg3BCs2BjKAcsZANpQJFFeIBQA)

```
              +    The output is the sum of
{           }ᶠ     all possible results of
 i                 taking a row from the input with its index,
  i                taking an element with its index
   ʰ               from that row,
    I    Ihh       and outputting the element
       =∧          so long as the index of the row is equal to
     -ʰ            the value of the element minus its index within the row.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
ArrayRules/*Cases[p_~_~v_/;Tr@p==v:>v]/*Tr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvLCoMwEEX3@YqC0IVMiPFRsEWx9AdKcScioUQq1CJJKpSgv54Oms3cM/fMjMK85CjM8BSuL9xVKfF7fN9Ss/AmtNTN1K3dOnfsUqtqKor5XM4tC2vl7mr4mCagZV8F7ZFVltgFiLXxsgWHDGKkg80h9ZRBDqddR5BABOlWYwL3nGLP/TmNUeCgfP9JkFAnm/QLKrK4Pw)

1-indexed.

```
ArrayRules                                  (*Convert into a list of (position->value) Rules*)
          /*Cases[p_~_~v_/;Tr@p==v          (*select those where sum(position)==value*)
                                  :>v]/*Tr  (*and find the sum of those values*)
```